# Linear regression of a categorical variable, calculating the β (95% CI) and P for trends

Tags: r, lm, p-value

I recently read an article by JAMA, titled "[Trends in Sedentary Behavior Among the US Population, 2001-2016](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31012934/)". I want to learn their method.

The article says this:

> "Crude linear trends in sedentary behaviors
> were evaluated using linear regression models across survey cycles and to estimate regression coefficients (β) and 95% CIs for every 2-year change. P for trends were estimated using the survey cycle as a continuous variable."

Please help me to fit a linear regression model and calculate this results.
I want to calculate the β (95% CI) and P for trend in the following picture.

[image]
The data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Year_group = c("2001-2002", "2003-2004", "2005-2006", "2007-2008", "2009-2010","2011-2012","2013-2014","2015-2016"),
  Incidence = c(65.5,72.6,61.0,63.2,61.8,63.6,57.6,62.2),
  CI_Lower = c(59.1, 68.1, 56.3, 57.8, 54.5,59.2,53.7,57.1),
  CI_Upper = c(72.0, 77.2, 65.7, 68.7, 69.1,68.0,61.4,67.2))
```

Comment: The first thing I would ask is what have you tried so far? The second thing is that if survey cycle is a continuous variable, I would look into turning `Year_group` into a continuous variable, i.e 1 for "2001-2002", 2 for "2003-2004" and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. I have tried to fit the linear regression model, however, I can not get the same result like the article of JAMA. The survey cycle is a category variable, presenting a period. i.e 2001-2002 for the period from 2001 to 2002. I have fitted the linear regression like this: 1 for 2001-2002, 2 for 2003-2004 and so on. But I can not get the same results like the article.

Comment: I'm not sure how they are getting those confidence intervals, when I fit a simple model of the incidences against cycle as a continuous variable, I got the same estimate of -1.1 but the CIs were wider. It could be they are including the ethnicity data or weights.

Comment: That's right, I made the "Year-group" as a continuous variable from 1 to 8, I get the -1.1 for β, but I can't get the same result of 95% CIs and P for trend.